# How to combine left join and subtract?

Tags: mysql

First table "Positions" contains information about items, available amount and price.

When somebody wants to buy an item, the system finds a position for that item with lowest price and create a reserve for it for some period of time.

**Positions:**

```
id item amount price seller
1  1    1      4     1
2  1    2      5     2
```

**Reserves:**

```
id position created_at 
1  1        1430060037
```

If another customer wants to buy the same item, only second position will be available for him, because first position has only one item (in amount) and that item has been reserved earlier. But if reserve#1 has been expired, customer could buy an item for the price from first position.

Updated:

**Positions:**

```
id  item amount price
1   1    2      4
2   1    2      5
3   1    2      6
```

**Reserves:**

```
id  position  created_at
1   1         1430060037
1   1         1430060038
```

In this case, I want to get position#2 with price#5, because all items from position#1 are reserved.

Comment: Please post your table definitions and explain the phrase "considering reserves which were created less than 60 seconds ago."

Comment: Eech field is integer, id is primary key. When somebody reserves an item in position, a new entry created in reserves table, but it only valid for 60 seconds. After that the reserve is not taken into account.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know which item is described in the `reserves` table? Does `id` refer to the item there? Or something else? You need to explain your question much more clearly.

Comment: Only position in second table refers to first. There is no link to item. But it's possible to add a new column if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    `positions`.`amount`,
    MIN(`price`) AS `min_price`,
    COUNT(`reserves`.`id`) AS `reserve_count`
FROM `positions`
    LEFT JOIN `reserves` on `positions`.`id` = `reserves`.`position`
WHERE `positions`.`item` = 1234 -- specify the item here
    AND `created_at` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND
GROUP BY `reserves`.`position`
HAVING `reserve_count` != `amount`
```

Comment: A small addition.
Each position has an amount (of items). If number of reserves for the position is equel to its amount, than this position should be ignored in the result.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means. Try my edit and see if it does what you want.

Comment: I have updated a question, could you please correct your answer a little?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you want. Please edit your question to explain what the columns are (what they mean, not just what data type they contain). You may need to add a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Sorry, no; I'm still not sure I know what you mean. I made a little edit to my answer and think it will work for you. Let me know if it doesn't.